# How to prove the exterior measure of two disjoint open sets can be additive?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working with the following question:

> Let $G_1,G_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be two disjoint open sets. Prove that for any $E_1\subseteq G_1, E_2\subseteq G_2$, we have $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$.

I try to use the observation of the exterior measure:

> If $E=E_1\cup E_2$ and $d(E_1,E_2)>0$, then $m_*(E)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$.

But I had no idea to prove the distance between two disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ larger than $0$.

**Edited**:Now I know the statement that the distance between two disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ larger than $0$ is not correct. And I completely lost the idea to work with the question in the first block. Does somebody give any hints?

Comment: how you define the distance between two set. Set $d=1$ and consider $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$. These are disjoint but $d = \inf\{|x-y| :x\in (0,1), y\in (1,2)\}=0$

Comment: $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are two disjoint open sets.  It seems unlikely that the distance between them is positive...

Comment: @Mick $d(E_1,E_2)=\inf\{|x-y|, x\in E_1,y\in E_2\}$

Comment: What are the assumptions on $m_*$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two open sets can be zero. Even in $\mathbb R$, you can see this, since $d((-\infty, 0), (0,\infty)) = 0$.

In general, in $\mathbb R^d$, you can take

$$A_1 = \{(x_1,\dots, x_d)\in\mathbb R^d| x_1>0\}\\A_2 = \{(x_1,\dots, x_d)\in\mathbb R^d| x_1<0\}$$
and it should be easy to see that $d(A_1, A_2)=0$.

---

Note that two **closed** subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ can also be at a distance of $0$ from eachother. For example, in $\mathbb R$, you can have $$A_1=\left\{i + \frac1{2i}| i\in\mathbb R\right\}\\A_2=\left\{i - \frac1{2i}| i\in\mathbb R\right\},$$

that is $$A_1=\left\{1+\frac12, 2+\frac14, 3+\frac16, 4+\frac18,\dots\right\}\\A_2=\left\{1-\frac12, 2-\frac14, 3-\frac16, 4-\frac18,\dots\right\}$$

and have $d(A_1, A_2)=0$, since $d\left(i+\frac1{2i}, i-\frac1{2i}\right) = \frac1i$.

Comment: Both sets are equal, do you mean $x_1<0$ in $A_1$ or $A_2$?

Comment: @Marm Yes, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, and I just modified the question. Can you give any hints?